# (Primefaces 10.0) alignments of elements inside the <p:row> component is broken

Tags: primefaces

I switched from Primefaces version 8.0 to version 10.0. After the switch, the alignment of the objects in the <p:row> component is broken. If I don't add elements as a column in <p:row>, it doesn't get fixed.

For example this code has alignment problems:

```
<p:row>     
        <div class = "ui-grid-col-6 PadRight1Per ResPadRightPer1To0">
        <p:selectOneMenu id = "someDataHere" converter="elemanConverter" required = "true" value = "#{ControllerHere}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel = "#ValueHere" itemValue = "" />
        <f:selectItems itemLabel = "#{ValueHere}" itemValue = "#{ValueHere}" value = "#{ControllerHere}" var = "?" />
        <p:ajax global = "true" listener = "#{ControllerHere}" process = "@this" update = "@this" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div> 
        <div class = "ui-grid-col-6 PadLeft1Per ResPadLeftPer1To0">   
        <p:selectOneMenu id = "someDataHere" required = "true" value = "#{ControllerHere}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel = "#{ValueHere" itemValue = "" />
        <f:selectItems itemLabel = "#{ValueHere}" itemValue = "#{ValueHere}" value = "#{ControllerHere}" var = "?" />
        <p:ajax global = "true" listener = "#{ControllerHere}" process = "@this" update = "@this" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div>          
</p:row>
```

After I add <p:column> like that problem solves:

```
<p:row> 
    <p:column>
        <div class = "ui-grid-col-6 PadRight1Per ResPadRightPer1To0">
        <p:selectOneMenu id = "someDataHere" converter="elemanConverter" required = "true" value = "#{ControllerHere}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel = "#ValueHere" itemValue = "" />
        <f:selectItems itemLabel = "#{ValueHere}" itemValue = "#{ValueHere}" value = "#{ControllerHere}" var = "?" />
        <p:ajax global = "true" listener = "#{ControllerHere}" process = "@this" update = "@this" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div> 
        <div class = "ui-grid-col-6 PadLeft1Per ResPadLeftPer1To0">   
        <p:selectOneMenu id = "someDataHere" required = "true" value = "#{ControllerHere}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel = "#{ValueHere" itemValue = "" />
        <f:selectItems itemLabel = "#{ValueHere}" itemValue = "#{ValueHere}" value = "#{ControllerHere}" var = "?" />
        <p:ajax global = "true" listener = "#{ControllerHere}" process = "@this" update = "@this" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div> 
    <p:column>      
</p:row>
```

But I have 2000 elements like this in my app, Is there any way to fix all of this completely? What should I do?

What I mean by alignment problems (like graduation date):
[image: Alignment Problem]

Comment: So, basically, your question is: how do I find and replace in files, right?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Is there a method to solve all of these at once? I tried throwing css, grid files to my project from Primefaces 8.0 but it didn't work. It would be great to get it working properly as it is. Not all of them are in this structure, so they are not solved only when p:column is added.

Comment: I think you have no choice but to add `<p:column>` it is a requirement of using `<p:row>`

Comment: @Melloware thank you, I have no other choice unfortunetly